# How run my own android emulator in window?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

In linux, I built my own emulator(follow instruction: http://source.android.com ) and started it ok. Now, I want to copy it to Windows and run it. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think the following steps can help you. You need to copy the following files (I give also paths to these files) into your folder in Windows (lets assume that this folder is `user_folder`):

```
out/target/product/generic/system.img
out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
out/target/product/generic/userdata.img
prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu
```

If in Windows you have Android SDK installed then there should be command `emulator`. You may need also put there an image for sdcard (which can be generated using mksdcard) You need just fill the parameters of this command.

```
emulator -sysdir <path_to_your_user_folder> -system <path_to_your_user_folder>/system.img -ramdisk <path_to_your_user_folder>/ramdisk.img -data <path_to_your_user_folder>/userdata.img -kernel <path_to_your_user_folder>/kernel-qemu -sdcard <path_to_your_user_folder>/sdcard.img
```

Comment: I do same as you said but it don't work for me. When i enter command above then one emulator started but it's screen black, nothing is display.I run: adb devices -> result: emulator-5554 offline. Any suggestion for me?

Comment: Could you run also adb logcat and check if the emulator starts?

Comment: I haven't been run adb logcat, i will try after i login in windows (i am loggin in linux). I have a idea that I build Android sdk for Windows then I will have sdk and emulator, I built Android SDK for Linux/MacOS success but When i built for Windows I get same error "/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread ". What can i do to fix that?

Comment: The main problem is resolved. I replace images of emulator SDK Linux/MacOs to images of emulator in Windows, then it worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is to build your own Android SDK (for Windows) from source. You can do that like this:

Setup:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mingw32 tofrodos
```

mingw32 is the cross-compiler, tofrodos adds a unix2dos command.

To build:

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk-eng
$ make win_sdk
```

Taken from [here](http://tools.android.com/build) (Building the Windows SDK).

If it doesn't work, lunch the emulator with more debug options (e.g.: **-show-kernel**) and see where it stops. Since it doesn't get to the point of initializing the adbd deamon, this might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Download Android SDK for windows which comes with emulator .
[Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Or you can other android player like [Blue Stacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

or you can run Android OS (image file) directly on windows using emulators like Vmware.

Good Luck!!!